# Navbar different height for collapsed

Tags: css, height, navbar

My Bootstrap navbar looks great when it's extended out but when it collapses the buttons become rows that are way too high. The menu takes up the whole screen on an iPhone. Is there any way of having two different heights? One for the big screen, the other for smaller screens?

Thanks

EDIT: Since I asked I did find the @media at the bottom of the css file and  added a height attribute there but it didn't change the 'active' button. I then tried to add that the the @media and it din't work. However, when I did this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-nav>.active>a  {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
height:33px;
line-height:33px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
color: #FD851A;
background-color: #1b3f65;
line-height: 33px;
}}
```

it works, but I know it's not right with two @media there. How do I merge those those together?

Thanks, I'm not very good at this!

Answer (score 0):

Please change the style property of `.navbar-collapse.in` class to the following. You can locate the following class from style sheet called bootstrap.css. I recommend to update the mentioned styles from the width `@media (min-width: 768px) {}`

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 'height';
}
```

I am attaching the screenshot after I applied the styles to the mentioned class.
[image]

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me, Fazil, but I'm sure I did something wrong. I edited my original post though.

Comment: I have update my answer. There are already have the '.navbar-collapse.in' class under the '@media (min-width: 768px)'. Please update the class instead of the current one.